# Alpha-numeric dialpad search - Java/Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm creating a search that filters a 2-D string array if it contains a specific string. The user can search while dialing a number corresponding to the dial pad (0-9). For example, if the numbers 56 are typed, the search would look for any string sequence containing '56', 'JJ', 'JM', JO', 'KM', 'KN', 'KO', 'LM', 'LN', 'LO' in the 2-D array.

My approach is to store the possibilities in an array and then loop through the 2-D array to see if any of them contain the sequence; nested loops. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this or a link to something similar before I spend several hours writing it.

Comment: Does it have to be a 2D array? I think you would be much better off using an ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList inside an ArrayList?

Comment: ArrayList of StringPair Objects? Where String pair is a very simple object class to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be (if it has to be an array) to build a subset of possible names based on the entered letters, and after each letter is entered comparing the subset rather than the full set.

For example if you started with

```
Bill, Bob, Conroy, Fran, Riley, Shelley
```

After entering a 2 (A,B,C) you would be left with

```
Bill, Bob, Conroy, (Fran if contains)
```

Then after entering 6 (M,N,O) you would be left with

```
Bob, Conroy, (Fran if contains)
```

**If Starts With**
In order to do this you would need a collection of the indices which have currently been matched, a List would probably be the best implementation

```
List<Integer> indicesMatched;
```

**If Contains**
You would need to store the index of the matched string and also the index of where the first matched letter is within the string, possibly as a map ( or a List and mis-use the Point class)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> matched;  // where the key is the array index and the value is the string index
```

Then you can populate this with the first set of matched indices. Then when you compare the second number/letter only use those indices stored in the list and for each remove those which do not match the second letter

Pseudo Code: (for starts with)

```
// First key press
// For each entry in your array
    // If a match
       // Add to matched index List

// Second Key Press -- Repeat this step for each subsequent key press
// For each index in list
    // Get the entry at that index
       // If not a match in second letter
           // Remove the index from list
```

Pseudo Code: (for contians)

```
// First key press
// For each entry in your array
    // If a match
       // Add to matched index map

// Second Key Press -- Repeat this step for each subsequent key press
// For each index in map
    // Get the entry at that index
       // If not a match in second letter (based on the stored string index)
           // Remove the index from map
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Array with all your searched Strings (names, I'm guessing, in this case), then I would write it such that:

1. User enters a number, let's say 5
2. You now know that first letter is J, K or L
3. Search through your array until you find first J, set up an index marker calling it "start"
4. Continue searching until you get to last element starting with L, and add an index marker calling it "end"
5. Repeat for next number, but this time instead of searching the entire array, merely search from "start" marker to "end" marker, and readjust both as needed.

Consider the case:

`Adam
James
Kevin
Laurie
Lisa
Steve`

User enters a 5, so we loop through and determine:

```
start = 1; //index of "James"
end = 4; //index of "Lisa"
```

So our array is down to

`James
Kevin
Laurie
Lisa`

Now the user enters another number, and we do it again with this (much smaller, given a full address book) array, but this time comparing the second letter in each name, eliminating indices that do not fit into the possibilities. So, again, if the user enters a 2 now, that means possible letters are A, B, and C. The array gets wittled down again to:

`James
Laurie`

And so on.

Comment: Your initial method of getting a start and end index would not work for the second number/letter entered. If they entered 2 like you suggest, repeating the outlined method you would get a result of `James Kevin Laurie`

Comment: You're right, to do it that way one would have to put the sub-array into a new array, then sort it with a user-defined Comparator based on the second letter. This might be overkill, so just using an ArrayList and removing elements starting with the second iteration would be easier.